# Conditional Cached Page Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, browser-cache, redirect

I am trying to set up a conditional cached re-direct depending on the website viewers choice.

Here's an example of how I am looking to have the website function ( you can test this by going to vonage.com):

When I visit www.vonage.com, I have a choice between "For Personal, For Small Business, For Mid-Market & Enterprise".

After making the choice, you'll be sent to the associated website/subdomain - either vonage.com, personal.vonage.com, or enterprise.vonage.com.

Then, if you try to go back to the initial page with choices, you won't be able to, you're redirected back to the choice that you've already made.

How is this done?  I would like to implement something similar.  I'm using Wordpress by the way, but that probably won't matter, I can get my hands dirty in the code or .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, and this is java-script only not php, but a cookie should do the trick.

on page load check if the cookie exists, if it does redirect, if not don't:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("home") >= 0) {
 // redirect them to home
}
else if (document.cookie.indexOf("business") >= 0) {
 // redirect them to business
}
else if (document.cookie.indexOf("enterprise") >= 0) {
 // redirect them to enterprise
}
```

if none of those trigger, and the user is not redirected when they choose an option set their cookie, for example:

```
// set a new cookie
expiry = new Date();
expiry.setTime(date.getTime()+(10*60*1000)); // Ten minutes

// Date()'s toGMTSting() method will format the date correctly for a cookie
document.cookie = "business; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I'll try it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Great let me know if you run into any issues, probably want to up the math to make it last longer then 10 minutes too.

Comment: Cookies are probably the best way to go here but might be worth transferring this logic to php at the WordPress routing level rather than waiting for the browser layer to load then perform this logic

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(href, referrer) {
    var enterprise = "http://enterprise.mysite.com" 
    var personal = "http://personal.mysite.com" 

    var is_enterprise = new RegExp(enterprise).test(href)
    var is_personal = new RegExp(personal).test(href)

    var cache = readCookie('portal')
    if (cache) return location.href = cache

    var portal = is_enterprise || is_personal
    if (portal) document.cookie = "portal=" + (enterprise || personal) + "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";

    return null
})(location.href, document.referrer)


function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```